# mouse simulation in windows

Tags: c#, hardware, mouseevent

I am writing a desktop program using c#, which works with a mouse-like hardware designed for people with disabilities. Now I can read the data from hardware and simultaneously update the cursor position by updating Cursor.Position. The program works pretty well.However when I try to use my program while playing a 3D game(a fps for example) it doesn't work. When I move the hardware the cursor in the game is not updated. I have tried it with a few 3D games. Is there a way that I can move the mouse cursor in the games move programatically. I guess the game engines doesn't use the cursor position. Instead they get the x and y difference from hardware. Is there a way to directly manipulate this data ? so that my hardware and program can be used while playing a game. Hope i was clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a driver for that hardware. If you handle the events of your "mouse-a-like" hardware in your c# program it is fine, but it won't work in other programs.

Comment: Thanks, will I be communicating with some windows API or should I go more low level ? I'd appreciate if you have worked about it before and can give more clues.

Comment: @OzgurTmp: I'm very sorry, but I haven't implemented a mouse driver yet. You should ask that question to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks anyway, now at least i know what to look for ;)